# com.octo.captcha + PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer valueSeparator conflict

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have an extremely strange issue. I'll try to simplify it to explain in better way. 
I have a project, everything works fine, I use application context with the following bean:

```
<bean id="props" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
   <property name="locations">
      <list>
         <value>/WEB-INF/oxygen.properties</value>
      </list>
   </property>
   <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
</bean>
```

And then I declare beans like

```
<bean id="authSiteParamsBean" class="comtech.swm.domain.index.AuthSiteParamsBean">
   <constructor-arg index="0" value="${swc.login:oxygen}" />
   <constructor-arg index="1" value="${swc.password:oxygen}" />
   <constructor-arg index="2" value="${swc.proxyHost:8080}" />
   <constructor-arg index="3" value="${swc.endpoints:smth}" />
</bean>
```

Everything works great. But if I add just these lines to pom.xml

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.octo.captcha</groupId>
   <artifactId>jcaptcha-all</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-RC6</version>
</dependency>
```

value separator just stops working! So when everything works fine I either get value from .properties file or default value. But with this dependency I get just strings like "${swc.login:oxygen}". So, I tried to modify my properties bean and declare property valueSeparator explicitly:

```
<bean id="props" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
   <property name="locations">
      <list>
         <value>/WEB-INF/oxygen.properties</value>
      </list>
   </property>
   <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
   <property name="valueSeparator" value=":" />
</bean>
```

And what do I get?

> SEVERE: Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'props' defined in ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/appContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException:
>   Invalid property 'valueSeparator' of bean class
>   [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer]:
>   Bean property 'valueSeparator' is not writable or has an invalid
>   setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return
>   type of the getter? Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid
>   property 'valueSeparator' of bean class
>   [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer]:
>   Bean property 'valueSeparator' is not writable or has an invalid
>   setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return
>   type of the getter?

Please, help! I want to go on using this captcha lib and default values.

Comment: You don't need to use `valueSeparator` as default one is `:`, and how you pass value like `${swc.login}` in constructor-arg?

Comment: I know it's not necessary, I just wanted to show you the error. What do you mean how I pass them? <constructor-arg index="0" value="${swc.login:oxygen}" /> like this, it's from my post.

Comment: I means you should pass only `key` so should be `<constructor-arg index="0" value="${swc.login}" />`, as example key-value pair in your `oxygen.properties` file is like `swc.login=oxygen`, right?

Comment: Right, but I use default values for cases when I don't have values in oxygen.properies. So I cannot use just ${swc.login} without default value ${swc.login:oxygen}, because otherwise we can have problems after deployment. We have scripts that restore old configuration files, from previous versions, so default values are necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the exact reason and the solution. I built dependency tree via IDEA and saw that captcha library depends on old spring framework (2.0) which doesn't support default values for properties. So I simply use this in pom.xml now, and it works perfect:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.octo.captcha</groupId>
   <artifactId>jcaptcha-all</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-RC6</version>
   <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

[image]